# Displaying an image from the resource issue

Tags: android, sqlite, resources

I am displaying an image in my `ListView`. I stored the image in my drawable folder *R.drawable.image.* Eveything is working great

```
AddObjectToList(R.drawable.image)
```

Howver now I decided to sore the location in my sqllite db as a string *"R.drawable.image*". I need to parse it into a integer so I did this:

```
    AddObjectToList(Integer.parseInt(imageelist3.get(i).toString()
```

Getting this error

```
ComponentInfo{myproject}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse 'R.drawable.image' as integer
```

Any idea how to resolve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have to understand the meaning of `R.drawable.image`

Here R is a `class R` of auto-generated java file from android application,
which contains other class `class drawable` in that `image is a int variable`.

Its a int value and you are storing it as string then converted it in int which is wrong.

**Just store int values of R.drawable.image**.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! where can I find the int value of R.drawable.image?

Answer (score 0):

"R.drawable.image" is not already int? Try to save to database directly "R...." with out parse it to integer.